# Sending array of objects in one request in parse push notification rest service

Tags: java, rest, parse-platform, push-notification

I am able to send parse push notification using Rest API containing single object as below:

```
{"data":{"badge":"increment","alert":"test push notification"},"channels": ["vkanse"]}
```

But instead,I want to send different messages to different users and would want to use array of objects to avoid sending multiple request to parse. A sample request is as below:

```
[
{
"data": {
  "badge": "increment",
  "alert": "Message 1"
},
"channels": [
  "user1",
  "user2"
]
},
{
"data": {
  "badge": "increment",
  "alert": "Message 2"
},
"channels": [
  "user3"
]
}
]
```

But I searched the Parse documentation and was unable to find a json request having array of objects. Is it even possible??

This is the Rest API am using to send push notification.
      https://api.parse.com/1/push

Please help me here...

Comment: Please show the code that you are using.

Comment: Not sure if this will work for pushes as well, the documentation only speaks of objects, but there is a batch API which might be worth a try. https://www.parse.com/docs/rest/guide#objects-batch-operations